# why does the result of loading binary between on linux and on arm are so different?

Tags: c

In essence, I want my main program to link properly to one library 'libA.so', and the symbols 'subFunc' from that library may come from another library(xxx), but those symbols 'funcB' will not be used by the main program.
I compile them as follows:
libA.so

```
int subfunc(int a, int b);
int funcB(int a, int b) {
    return subfunc(a, b);
}

int funcA(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

main.cc

```
#include <stdio.h>
int funcB(int a, int b);
int main()
{
  funcB(1,2);
  printf("hello\n");
  return 0;
}
```

```
gcc --shared libA.cc -o libA.so
gcc main.cc libA.so -o main -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined
```

./main
'./main' can run normally on linux,but when I cross compile them:

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc --shared libA.cc -o libA.so
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc main.cc libA.so -o main -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined
```

then run on platform 'arm',
'./main' get notification:
./main: symbol lookup error: libA.so: undefined symbol: _Z7subfuncii

Any advices for me, I will be very grateful.

Comment: Why `.cc` and not just `.c` (question tagged as c)? Maybe the crosscompiler try to treat the source as c++ file beacuse of this. But just a guess based on the mangled like name of `_Z7subfuncii`.

Comment: bro, thanks for your reply. when I use g++ exactly got "undefined symbol: _Z7subfuncii" on linux. But why there is no error using gcc on linux.

Comment: you are welcome and don't know why there is no error tho.

Comment: The error message `undefined symbol: _Z7subfuncii` makes perfect sense: In `libA.cc`, you declared `int subfunc(int a, int b);`, but you never implemented it. No wonder the compiler cannot find this symbol. I guess you will also get an error on the other compiler once you enable all warnings. (`-Wall --pedantic`).

Comment: Xaver, thanks for your reply. what you said is correct. I wonder why it works with compiler gcc. even if 'subfunc' is never be implemented.